# Why latch doesn't get inferred for following logic?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, vlsi

Why following code does not infer latch?

How does tool know what to be assigned to "e" if d and rst both are "0" ?

```
module tmp(input d,
        input clk,
        input rst,
        output reg o,
        output reg e);

 always@(posedge clk)
         if(rst) begin
               o <=0;
               e <= 1;
               end
         else if(d) begin
                     o<=1;
                     e<=0;
               end
          else
                    o <=1;
endmodule
```

Comment: `e` will retain it's last value. And since you have an edge sensitive design, not a level sensitive, a FF would be inferred, not a latch.

Answer (score 2):

Your always block models *sequential logic* (ie logic with flip-flops in). If `d` and `rst` are both `1'b0`, then no line of code with an assignment to `e` will be executed. Consequently, `e` will retain (ie remember) its previous value. But that's OK, because `e` will be synthesied as a D-type flip-flop. Flip-flops have state, they have (are) storage. No latch is required.

Comment: So Is it that, always @ (posedge ** ) made tool to infer FF? And due to priority logic if before flop, "e" is not changing it's state; hence over-all avoiding "latch" ? 
While, always@(**) ; if I would have written same logic; then it would have inferred latch because there is no FF/Memory element to store previous state(which is default).
Thank you all for answers.

Comment: Yes, always @ (posedge ** ) makes the tool to infer a FF. (What other logic component has outputs that change on a clock edge?)